# Config DBConfig.ExtraParams not specified for ml-pipeline pod

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I have installed Kubeflow using manifest. After installing ml-pipeline, the pod is in "CrashLoopBackOff" state. I changed the destinationrule for ml-pipeline, ml-pipeline-ui and ml-pipeline-msql to DISABLE but no luck. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of possible root causes for this POD’s status, but I am going to try to focus on the most common ones. To choose the correct one for your accurate situation, you are going to need to take a look into the “describe” and the log from the POD with "CrashLoopBackOff" state.

Verify if the “describe” says something like “Back-off restarting failed container” and the log says something like “a container name must be specified for …”, “F ml_metadata/metadata_store/metadata_store_server_main.cc:219] Non-OK-status …”.

If yes, the problem is the dynamic volume provisioning regularly, maybe because no volume provisioner is installed.

On the other hand, you can verify your cluster’s size, because anything less than 8 CPUs is going to run only if you reduce each service’s requested cpu in the manifest files.

You do not give details on the affected POD yet; but another option is to try to install Katib only (without Kubeflow or other resources) on your K8s cluster to verify other Kubernetes resources do not affect this connection. You can use the following URL’s information for more empirical cases’ troubleshooting and solutions: [Multiple Pods stuck in CrashLoopBackOff](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/5468), [katib-mysql](https://github.com/kubeflow/katib/issues/1415) , [ml-pipeline-persistenceagent pod keeps crashing](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/4258).

Finally just confirm that you followed the correct instructions, based on the Distribution you used to deploy Kubeflow, you can visit the following URL: [Kubeflow Distributions](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/distributions/)

Comment: Hi, I tried this it is not working

Comment: Exactly which troubleshooting did you follow? And which Distribution of Kubeflow did you use? Could you please paste the log's and describe's information, editing your first question?

Comment: I installed kubeflow from this repository 
https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests

Comment: Supposing that you used: <<while ! kustomize build example | kubectl apply -f -; do echo "Retrying to apply resources"; sleep 10; done>> ... that means you installed all the components and I suggested you to user only "katib" to see if the rest of the components are affecting the connection.

Comment: Yeah this same thing is working fine in AKS but this error I am getting only in GKE

Comment: Can you please follow the recommended troubleshooting steps in GKE, accurately and could you let us know the result?  Plus, the info from your PODs log and describe from GKE? Here are the commands to get PODs info inside of GKE: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#get

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238581/discussion-between-nestor-daniel-ortega-perez-and-ashis).